# PublicNetworkAccess for Azure SQL Server logical server

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I recently started exploring the Azure sql server service, and I created several servers with different configurations.
On of the feature of azure sql server is public network access that allows to give access to the sql server from public internet.
This field appears as "publicNetworkAccess" when we retrieve the JSON format of the entity, and can have 2 values: "Enabled" or "Disabled". But I noticed that sometimes this field also had the value "null".
How to create an Azure SQL Server so that the "publicNetworkAccess" field is null?
Thank you all for your help
Here the link of the property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.sql.models.server.publicnetworkaccess?view=azure-dotnet-legacy
And for instance an entity JSON format with the field publicNetworkAccess:

```
{
"kind": "v12.0",
"properties": {
    "administratorLogin": "jonasAdmin",
    "version": "12.0",
    "state": "Ready",
    "fullyQualifiedDomainName": "jonas.database.windows.net",
    "privateEndpointConnections": [],
    "minimalTlsVersion": "None",
    "publicNetworkAccess": "Enabled",
    "restrictOutboundNetworkAccess": "Disabled"
},
"location": "eastus",
"id": "/subscriptions/aaaaaa-1111-1111-222222222222/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Sql/servers/jonas",
"name": "jonas",
"type": "Microsoft.Sql/servers"
}
```

Comment: Why do you want it to be null?

Comment: I want to check if I can still access my server by adding my IP to the firewall rule of the server. So, I want to create a server with publicNetworkAccess set to null in order to test the accessibility of my server.

Comment: I couldn't find any value as 'NULL' while assigning `publicNetworkAccess`. Share the screenshot if any with NULL.

Answer (score 0):

> How to create an Azure SQL Server so that the "publicNetworkAccess" field is null?

When you create a logical server there are only two options are available **`Enabled/Disabled`** as we have to access server from any IP we need to pass that add that IP in firewall and we can allow the access of server. If we want the particular network people only access the server, we need to disable public access and add private network details.

You can clearly see in this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.sql/new-azsqlserver?view=azps-11.2.0#-publicnetworkaccess)

> Its flag value that only accept enabled/disabled as value